Dynamic Textbox in ArcGIS Online to Supplement Legend?
We have an ArcGIS Online Web Map with several group layers organized around themes (Transportation, Health, Income, etc) and each with about 5 layers.
Our goal is to have a web mapping application that has a dynamic text box next to the legend. The default view would be nothing shown and then the user would turn on group layers and/or individual layers.
If the user chooses the "transportation" group layer then we would like to have the text box next to the legend filled in with a brief blurb describing the data and what it represents. If multiple group layers are chosen, then having both descriptions there works as well.
Is this possible in ArcGIS Online? We have tried using Experience Builder and Instant Apps and have not been able to figure it out.

Having the interactive you seeks suggests strongly its an experience builder site you want, I've not tried it but have an explore of the text widget, may be the connect to data will give you that hook into the layer? Or not! :)

This is not really possible in AGOL Experience Builder. Dynamic text boxes really only link to data (not webpage elements) and are not able to be toggled using webpage elements in any fashion.
That being said - How I've created a similar experience before:
Create a separate map for each group layer, add each map to a different view in a section. Then add a views navigation element to enable the user switching between the different maps. You can then add a "When Extent Changes > Pan To" action between every map. This way you can effectively let the end user interact with each section individually how your group layers are configured, and also create a custom blurb/text overlays for each individual map.
Side note: you will need to add the text boxes inside the map widgets and not over top of them. this will ensure they change when the section view changes.
